# Implementing the ordinals in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I've begun learning Haskell, and I thought I would implement the ordinal numbers, using the common ("von Neumann") definition. So I wrote:

```
ordinal 0 = []
ordinal x = [ ordinal n | n<-[1..(x-1)] ]
```

But the interpreter was not satisfied, and it told me instead that supposedly

```
    * Couldn't match type `a' with `[a]'
Expected: t -> a
Actual: t -> [a]
* Relevant bindings include
ordinal :: t -> a (bound at fist.hs:7:1)
|
1 | ordinal 0 = []
| ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

Now what I imagine might have gone wrong here is that the list is not of homogeneous type. But how would I switch to tuples then? Is there such a thing as "tuple comprehension"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The result of this function is a single empty value, or a list of such, or a list of lists, or a list of lists of lists, etc., depending on the input number. There is no single list type which can represent all these values.

... or is there? That type is not a list (i.e. `[]`) which only represents a single flat sequences of values, but there is such a type:

```
data Ordinal = Zero | Ordinal [Ordinal] deriving Show
```

and your function should be modified to wrap each such level of list nesting in an `Ordinal` constructor:

```
ordinal 0 = Zero
ordinal x = Ordinal [ ordinal n | n<-[1..(x-1)] ]
```

Example:

```
*Main> ordinal 3
Ordinal [Ordinal [],Ordinal [Ordinal []],Ordinal [Ordinal []]
```

Comment: Ah, very nice, so we create our own type. Admittedly, I had not progressed to that chapter in my Haskell online book. Thank you very much indeed. EDIT: I will confirm your answer as valid in a moment, when I've fully understood it.

Comment: That type doesn't make a lot of sense IMO. I mean, Von Neumann ordinals don't make much sense in the first place, but if you're going to have them then you should do it properly with _set_ not lists, and with no redundant representation for zero.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid I'll have to come to the defence of Mr. von Neumann here. After all, his definition of ordinal numbers is quite the natural one if you want to have them be sets and not classes. Thus, the mathematical structure of ordinal numbers is embedded within set theory. For a mathematician, that's nice. (I do understand that if one is not interested in such purely theoretical considerations, one would not consider them useful.)

Comment: The (unnecessary) extra zeros here can be removed as in @leftaroundabout's answer.

Answer (score 7):

First, lists aren't sets.

Second, lists require all elements to have the same type, so you can't have lists of different nesting depth in one list.

But from the “*everything* is a set” perspective that such constructions as Von Neumann ordinals are based on, you can just define a “universal type” based on sets:

```
import qualified Data.Set as Set

newtype UntypedSet = UntypedSet { getUntypedSet :: Set.Set UntypedSet }
 deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

ordinal :: Int -> UntypedSet
ordinal 0 = UntypedSet $ Set.empty
ordinal x = UntypedSet $ Set.fromList [ ordinal n | n <- [0..x-1] ]
```

Note the definition `[1..x-1]` was actually wrong in your implemetation, it should be `[0..x-1]`.

If you want to go quirky (not necessarily recommended), you can actually still use “list” notation:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies    #-}

import qualified Data.Set as Set
import GHC.Exts (IsList(..))

newtype UntypedSet = UntypedSet { getUntypedSet :: Set.Set UntypedSet }
 deriving (Eq, Ord)

instance IsList UntypedSet where
  type Item UntypedSet = UntypedSet
  fromList = UntypedSet . Set.fromList
  toList (UntypedSet s) = Set.toList s

instance Show UntypedSet where
  show = show . toList


ordinal :: Int -> UntypedSet
ordinal 0 = []
ordinal x = fromList [ ordinal n | n <- [0..x-1] ]
```

Then,

```
*Main> ordinal 4
[[],[[]],[[],[[]]],[[],[[]],[[],[[]]]]]
```

Comment: Thanks for this second excellent answer. Even though I am forced to tick the other answer because it was posted earlier, I will certainly upvote yours once I have fully understood it.

Comment: @AlgebraicsAnonymous You are certainly not forced to accept/tick the earliest answer. If you wish you can unaccept an answer by clicking the check mark, and then you’re free to accept another answer.

Comment: I thought the rule was to accept the earliest correct answer? The answers are both good in their own way: The first one is very easily understood and formulated politely, whereas the second gives an optically pleasing result.

Comment: I'll call it a night now; there are very many new concepts within your answer that I have yet to understand. I'll upvote your post anyway. Thanks a lot for your efforts.

Comment: @AlgebraicsAnonymous, there's absolutely no rule about which answer, if any, you should accept, or about when you should or shouldn't change your mind.

Comment: I like the fact that this representation isn't redundant. I don't like the fact that it can't even represent the first infinite ordinal.